# TopMost window - set only if there is "higher" Z ordered window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to have my form always Topmost (it follows mouse cursor), even above URL window in IE for example. That works when I add Topmost=true or BringToFront() to OnPaint method.
However, everything is OK but clicking on buttons in main form (the app consists of Form1 for options and transparent form2, following the mouse). If the form2 is always set to topmost, the clicks on form1 are not registered.
I have not found any workaround, i.e. something like if there is a control with higher Z coordinate, set this to topmost?
Hope it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: "What if two programs did this": http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx

Comment: @Johannes: I think it's bad enough having *one* program do this.

Comment: I need it for mouse-highlighting program to help my relative. Actually it works, there is red circle around the mouse cursor, but the topmost doesnt work always (like when you open URL list in IE).

Answer (score 0):

You can use SendMessage to pass mouse clicks to the form underneath.  See:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Programming_Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21549799.html

(Scroll to the bottom to see the answers).